# How many ways can you ascend a stairway of any number of steps?

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

I wrote out by hand every way from 1 to 6 steps and came up with the formula $f(x) = 2^{x-2}$. Is that correct? I then tried to solve the problem recursively but could not. So I wanted to know if my initial function was incorrect, or if i'm just too daft to find a recursive solution to this.

Comment: How exactly do you define a 'way'? Are you allowed to take more than 1 step at once? If so, how many?

Comment: What are our allowed moves? May I assume that we can only go up? How many steps can I jump at a time? It's easy to imagine a staircase where you can go 2 steps or even 3 at a time, not so much if you think about skipping 5 steps.

Comment: I was thinking any number of steps

Comment: isn't this a question about partitions? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: No, it's not about partitions. It's about counting subsets.

Comment: There is an one-one correspondence between the ways you move up the stairs and the collection of subsets of the set of $x-2$ "intermediate" stairs. For each way moving up the stairs, just associate it with the subset of "intermediate" stairs you have stepped upon during the move.

Answer (score 1):

Apparenly you want to move only up and forbid steps of size $0$ (naturally, as otherwise there are infinitely many solutions), and use of the first and last steps of the $n$ steps are obligatory. Then any solution is given by the subset of the remaining steps that are used, which indeed gives $2^{n-2}$ ways.

Answer (score 0):

You want all ways to get $6$ steps.

Mathematically we can see this as a *composition* of the number $6$:

$1+1+1+1+1+1$

$1+1+1+1+2$

$(\ldots)$

$6$

The number of compositions of $x$ is given by $2^{x-1}$. [See the Wikipedia article for a short proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29#Number_of_compositions).

Answer (score 0):

See here if I am no wrong then you are asking for : How many ways are there to break a number(integer) into several parts. such as: 3= 1+1+1 OR 1+2 OR 2+1 OR 3 So there is 4 ways to express 3 in such manner..ok..
if you have your question something like: if the number is  'n' then what would be the answer?....the you can have a look onto my question.....here we will map our problem into a similar problem which is easier to compute and very easy to follow....So here we go!!

Let us consider that we have a number  4(that is our n=4) now the question is how many ways are there to express 4 as we have done earlier for 3.

See here:   Let us now wriite 4 as four sticks ok.....so now we have :  { |     |     |     | } ok ...so we have 4 sticks in our hand.

Now see,we can easily observe that :  There are 3 spaces between 4 sticks and there are there 3 places to put  '+' SIGN or  a 'comma' SIGN (' , ') into these 3 places between these 4 sticks.ok...got it....

Now see,If we are interested to calculate the number of ways to express this number(n=4) like this special manner as done for 3 earlier , you can easily say that the number of possible ways is nothing but HOW MANY WAYS ARE THERE TO PUT  A  ' + ' SIGN OR A  'COMMA' SIGN IN THESE 3 places....

Because,
See here if we have an arrangement like this:   { | + | , | , | } ------(Here we have expressed the number 4 as:  2  1  1, It  has a sum of 4)
Now if we have an arrangement like this:       { | , |+| + | }------------(Here we have expressed the number n=4 as: 1  3, It has a sum of 4)

```
      So you can see that the number of possible arrangements is nothing but : in how many ways we can place + sign and comma sign mutually inbetween the gaps between the sticks that helps us to compute the number of ways to break any number n.
```

So,  we have the case for n=4 is: 2^(4-1) = 2^3 = 8.Because we have 3 places between 4 sticks.So the places admissible for the signs arre only 3 for the 4 sticks OR  there are only 3 gaps where we can put the + or COMMA sign.

Now if we have the nummber 'n' in general we will have:    { |     |     |     |  - - - | } .....(there are 'n' number of sticks and we have (n - 1) number of gaps between them where we can put the + OR the COMMA sign.)

Then, we can infer that we have total of :  2^(n -1) possible ways to break a number 'n' having highest length equals to 'n' because you can see that the number 4 can be written as : 4 itself,it is also a way to express this number.

but ingeneral we have found the closed formula for 'n' and it is:   [ 2^( n - 1) ]

Hope this above discussion will help you a bit.Best of luck.